# Bracket extension save listener

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to figure out how to add a listener that triggers when the current file open saved or a file is deleted in the open project.

I looked in the API and found this http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/document/Document.html#Document-notifySaved but the documentation isn't really good and I have no idea how to use it.

Has anybody had any experience accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -

```
   $(DocumentManager).on('documentSaved workingSetAdd pathDeleted', fileSavedHandler);
```

and

```
function fileSavedHandler($event, listener){
    //Code here
}
```